# How to extract li from ul in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I know the question may seem very basic but I can't seem to extract the li and the text from the given uls.

https://solar.world.org/reuse/Aluminum.Foil

Here is the url I am trying to extract. I have tried using find_all for ul but that gives me a weird return result and I can't use it to extract any text from the li.

In theory this code should work.

```
page = requests.get('https://solar.world.org/reuse/Aluminum.Foil')
soup = BSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for i in soup.find_all('ul'):
    for j in i.find_all('li'):
        print(j.text)
```

but its not.

Comment: Can you update the code you've provided here such that it meets the standards of a [mre]?

Comment: this is one crazy web page. You will really need to work on understanding the structure better to scrape it - I don't think it will be easy! Good luck!

Comment: @esqew Hello, Sir. I updated the code. Please take a look at it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page has **very** bad formatting (not your fault). Use a better parser to parse it:

```
soup = BSoup(page.content, 'html5')
```

Comment: Thank You very much! I was banging my head as it seemed so basic.